# Dropzone sailsjs nodejs upload image NetworkError: 404 Not Found

Tags: ajax, node.js, sails.js, dropzone.js, owl-carousel

I use Sails.js, which is based on Node.js. For the upload I use Dropzone. To display the pictures I use owl-carousel.

When I add a new picture and I try to display it I receive the following error:

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:1337/superrare/b004421de079bb2531cc5cd6346d202d/dde8221dc9e0b750479cedd3924af191/dde8221dc9e0b750479cedd3924af191.png"

If I open the above link in another tab I can see the image, because it exists at the specific path. 
If I refresh the page I can see the picture in the owl carousel, with the same path that is displayed above.

If I modify the Dropzone code for testing purposes, on success add to carousel an older picture, the picture will be displayed -> `imagePath = '/superrare/b004421de079bb2531cc5cd6346d202d/d845a68e5a57acf2f879bcd50966cc11/d845a68e5a57acf2f879bcd50966cc11.png';`

So only when I try to add a new picture path I receive a 404 error...

If I add a delay of 5 seconds, the error is the same 404.

Here is my code

```
Dropzone.options.mydropzone = {
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    init: function () {
        var imageName, imagePath, imageID;
        var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all");
        myDropzone = this; // closure

        this.on("success", function (file, responseJson) {

            imageName = responseJson.createdAt;
            imagePath = responseJson.path;
            //imagePath = '/superrare/b004421de079bb2531cc5cd6346d202d/d845a68e5a57acf2f879bcd50966cc11/d845a68e5a57acf2f879bcd50966cc11.png';
            imageID = responseJson.id;

            var content = '<div class="item"><div id="visinput" class="container-img">'+
                            '<img file-id="' + imageID + '" src="' + imagePath +  '">'+
                        '</div></div>';
            // get owl element
            var owl = $("#owlUpload");
            // add item to owl carousel
            setTimeout(function () {
                owl.data('owlCarousel').addItem(content);
            }, 5000);

            document.getElementById("serverFile").value = fileProcess;
        });
    },
    paramName: "file",
    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif"
};
```

Comment: OWL Carousel is not OWL - wrong tag.

Comment: Try re initializing owl carousel using `reinit`.